# Scraping Webpage with Javascript Elements

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

So to preface the website I've been trying to scrape seems to have/use (I'm unsure about the jargon with things relating to web development and the like) javascript code and I've been having varying success trying to scrape different tables on different pages.

For instance on this page: http://www.tennisabstract.com/cgi-bin/player.cgi?p=NovakDjokovic I was easily able to 'inspect element' then go to `Network` find the correct 'Name' of the script and then find the Request URL I needed to get the table that I wanted. The code I used for this was:

```
url = 'http://www.minorleaguesplits.com/tennisabstract/cgi-bin/frags/NovakDjokovic.js'
content = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(content.text, 'html.parser')

table = soup.find('table', id='tour-years', attrs= {'class':'tablesorter'})
dfs = pd.read_html(str(table)) 
df = pd.concat(dfs)
```

However, now when I'm looking at a different page on the same site, say this one http://www.tennisabstract.com/charting/20190714-M-Wimbledon-F-Roger_Federer-Novak_Djokovic.html, I'm unable to find the Request URL that will allow me to eventually get the table that I want. I repeat the same process as I did above, but there's no `.js` script under the Network tab that has the table. I do see the table when I'm looking at the html elements, but of course I can't get it without the correct url.

So my question would be, how can I get the table from this page http://www.tennisabstract.com/charting/20190714-M-Wimbledon-F-Roger_Federer-Novak_Djokovic.html ?

TIA!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On looking at the source code of the html page, you can see that all the data is already loaded in the script tag. Only thing you want is extract the variable value and load it to beautifulsoup.

The following code gives all the variables and the values from script tag

```
import requests, re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

res = requests.get("http://www.tennisabstract.com/charting/20190714-M-Wimbledon-F-Roger_Federer-Novak_Djokovic.html")
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, "lxml")
script = soup.find("script", attrs={"language":"JavaScript"}).text

var_only = script[:script.index("$(document)")].strip()
```

Next you can use regex to get the variable values - https://regex101.com/r/7cE85A/1

Comment: Thank you for the reply! Just one thing; I'm getting an error at this line `var_only = script[:script.index("$(document)")].strip()`. It says `ValueError: substring not found`. Should it be an empty string?

Comment: @dejsdukes Accept the answer if it has solved your question

Comment: oh that's really weird I'm getting an empty string when I do `print(script)` is that supposed to happen. I'm not really really familiar with the `var_only=...` line and it's function. Thank you for the answer though

Comment: ok so I fixed my empty string problem by doing `script = soup.find("script", attrs={"language":"JavaScript"}).string` instead of `script = soup.find("script", attrs={"language":"JavaScript"}).text`

Comment: @dejsdukes Good to hear